# Using Timer inside a BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, backgroundworker

My application deals with real-time data. When a `Form` is opened, a `BackgroundWorker` is created and it fetches the data and does the processing.

Now I would like this entire cycle to run in a *5 second loop* so long as the `Form` is active or open. ie if the user opens `form1` and is still on it in 5 secs time then the `BackgroundWorker` will do all the fetching and processing again. Now if the user closes `form1` and opens `form2` then a new `BackgroundWorker` is created and it does the processing relevant to `form2`.

I'm done with the `BackgroundWorker` part but can't decide on how to loop the `BackgroundWorker`. Should I create a Timer inside the `BackgroundWorker` that fires every 5 seconds? Or do I chuck the `BackgroundWorker` and make do with just the Timer?

EDIT: I went with BGW inside Timer. So every 5 sec the timer calls BGW and if BGW is busy then it waits for it to complete.

Answer (score 1):

yeah of course you can do it using the timer object as shown below

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Start();

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //do the logic..
}
```

Comment: Why does 5000ms equal to 30 seconds?